# List not updating after Filtering with searchView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-filterable

I implemented searchView in android which filters data. It works correctly But after filtering data, when I add new data it does not show in recyclerView when I restart the app then it shows, I am also able to view that item after again searching something and then backspace it.
Here is My Adapter Class

```
package com.example.keepnotes;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Notes> arrNotes;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Notes> arrNotes, DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrNotes = arrNotes;
        this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    }

    public void setFilteredList(ArrayList<Notes> filteredList) {
        this.arrNotes = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.title.setText(arrNotes.get(position).title);
        holder.body.setText(arrNotes.get(position).text);
        holder.index.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));


        holder.llView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent iNext = new Intent(context, ViewActivity.class);
            iNext.putExtra("title", arrNotes.get(position).title);
            iNext.putExtra("text", arrNotes.get(position).text);
            iNext.putExtra("id", arrNotes.get(position).id);
            context.startActivity(iNext);
        });

        holder.llView.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            showDeleteDialog(position);
            return true;
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrNotes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, body, index;
        CardView llView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title_view);
            body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_text_view);
            index = itemView.findViewById(R.id.index);
            llView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_View);
            databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    private void showDeleteDialog(int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete view")
                .setMessage("Are you sure to delete")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24)
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        databaseHelper.notesDao().deleteNotes(new Notes(arrNotes.get(position).getId(), arrNotes.get(position).getTitle(), arrNotes.get(position).getText()));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

                });
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Here is My filterable function

```
    private void filterList(String text) {
        ArrayList<Notes> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Notes notes : arrNotes) {
            if (notes.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || notes.text.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(notes);
            }
            if (!(filteredList.isEmpty())) {
                adapter.setFilteredList(filteredList);
            }
        }

    }
```

Here I implemented SearchView

```
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filterList(newText);
                return false;
            }

        });
```

I updated data using live data using this

```
        modelView = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(notesModelView.class);
        modelView.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Notes>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Notes> notes) {
                arrNotes.clear();
                arrNotes.addAll(notes);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not able to get your question properly, can you please explain the exact problem which you are facing?

Comment: after searching, when I add something(via user) it does not display in the reycylerView Adapter. Until I reload my app

Comment: are you talking about recycleview list not refreshing after adding a new Item to It?

Comment: no, filterable does not show all items, instead it shows only filtered items even after deleting text and closing searchView

Comment: only after when i search something

Comment: Check answer, Hopefully It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your filterList() function like this -

```
private void filterList(String text) {
    if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<Notes> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Notes notes : arrNotes) {
            if (notes.title.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || notes.text.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(notes);
            }
            adapter.setFilteredList(filteredList);
        }
    }else{
        adapter.setFilteredList(arrNotes);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it works, and please can you explain how it works

Comment: After clearing text in SearchView It becomes an empty String, So I have added a check If the text is not empty then perform a filter operation else load the original list. Hope you understood.